# How to use $watch on ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

Once user select the value from dropdown tree i want to fire an event and call the service to get the description of the selected value and map it to another field(populatefield.html). How can i achieve this with below code...

test.html

```
<div multiselect-dropdown-tree ng-model="nonPersistentProcess.erhKey"  options="erhTreeviewOptions"></div>
```

populatefield.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="CustSegment"
                                        name="CustomerSegment"
                                        ng-model="processDTO.businessSegmentOrControlFunction"
                                        maxlength="512" disabled="disabled">
```

Ctrl.js

```
  $scope.$watch($scope.nonPersistentProcess.erhKey,function(newVal,oldVal){
          if(newVal > oldVal){
            ERhHirachyInfo.getErhInfo($scope.nonPersistentProcess.erhKey).then(function(response){
              $scope.erhObj = response.data;
            });
          }
       });
```

Comment: just watch the model like this`$scope.$watch("nonPersistentProcess.erhKey",function(newVal,oldVal){`

Comment: thanks i tried with quotes but $watch is not being called at all...

Comment: Can you prepare http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: sorry cannot use jsfiddle/plunker if you explain here i will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and make it worked by doing below code....

```
 $scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.nonPersistentProcess.erhKey.length},
            function(newVal,oldVal){
              if(newVal > oldVal)
                  {
                    ERhHirachyInfo.getErhInfo($scope.nonPersistentProcess.erhKey[0].id).then(function(response){
                    $scope.erhObj = response.data;
                    });
                  }
       });
```